# For following drop down list , 'required' attribute is not working

Tags: html

If user selects  " - - select - -" from options , it should be treated as blank field. It should trigger 'required' attribute so that the browser would show alert message while submitting the form as: "Please fill out this field" .

I tried hard but no solution found.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <select id="post" name="post" required="required" title="post you are applying for" class="formfield3" />

    <option value="0"> - - select - -</option>
    <option value="1">Mobile App Developer</option>
    <option value="2">DataBase Administrator</option>
    <option value="3">Search Engine Optimizer</option>
    <option value="4">Product Manager</option>
    <option value="5">HR Manager</option>

    </select>

<input type=submit>
</form>
```

I am using newest version chrome and 'required' is working for other tags such as textfields etc.

Comment: jQuery or pure JS? What have you tried as for JS/jQuery?

Comment: @LShetty, this has nothing to do with JS or jQuery

Comment: @Davidconrad, how would you show an alert upon submit then?

Comment: some typo hints : Dont end `<select` with `/>`, remember quotes arround `type="submit"`

Comment: @LShetty, browser automatic alerts because of 'required' attribute.

Comment: @davidkonrad I have edited but still not working.

Comment: @krupal, this was general hints only - not at all an answer :) Think Yauheni Leichanok has the right answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make browser treat it as a blank field, make it blank - change 0 to an empty string:

```
<select id="post" name="post" required="required" title="post you are applying for" class="formfield3" />

    <option value=""> - - select - -</option>
    <option value="1">Mobile App Developer</option>
    <option value="2">DataBase Administrator</option>
    <option value="3">Search Engine Optimizer</option>
    <option value="4">Product Manager</option>
    <option value="5">HR Manager</option>

</select>
```

Comment: +1 Seems right to me. Don't know why you got downvoted.

Comment: +1, the right answer, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select look for required : "A Boolean attribute indicating that an option with a **non-empty** **string** **value** **must** **be** **selected**.

Answer (score 0):

Following code did not work for me:

```
<select id="example1" name="example1" required="required" />
    <option value="0"> - - select - -</option>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
</select>
```

Following code worked for me:

```
<select id="example1" name="example1" required="required" />
    <option value=""> - - select - -</option>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
</select>
```

The difference being `value=""` vs `value="0"`